# This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. In my newly created Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am a beginner to Spring boot. When I created a spring boot application from https://start.spring.io/ and when I am going to run the application It shows the below White Label error page. It has only the newly created `Application.java` file. It's great pleasure to expect an answer from you!

[image]

Application.java

```
package com.markdown.auth.application;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add controllers and endpoints,which will return to you information that you want. Without these you'll get 404 error

Answer (score 2):

You can add `End Points` means `Controler` and BL in which what you want.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
go through this link